# Vscode error "zsh: command not found: python" (on macOs Monterrey 12.3.1)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have no idea on how to solve this, I've tried to

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

And also

```
brew install python
```

I'm new on this so I really don't know what I'm doing, if someone could explain why I'm supposed to write those lines on my terminal I'd be very grateful

Comment: Have you tried to install the python from the [official docs](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/)?

Answer (score 1):

after updating to macos Monterey 12.6.1 had similar problem.
Before this update, python referred to python2.7 which was removed completely  in the latest Monterey versions.
Using following fix:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Result:

```
python -V
Python 3.9.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: python3 file_name.py runserver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try `python3 --version` in your terminal window, if it returned the version details, then python is installed in your system.

Comment: Okay, then what to do next? I am also getting the same error while trying to run a .py file on my vscode ; $zsh: command not found: python$